# Why Java Applet isn't displaying?

Tags: java, html, netbeans, applet

I am trying to build a very simple program with java applet.

**The program should navigate to corresponding website as an user click on their links which are appearing on the applet window.**

**But in my case no applet window is popping up!** *Well there is a window popping up (below is the image) [image: window popping up] (as soon as I run the code) which is not the relevant with my program.*

.java:

```
    package stringpractice;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI;

public class Applet extends JApplet {
    private HashMap<String,URL>websiteInfo;
    private ArrayList<String>titles;
    private JList mainList;

    private void inIt(){
        websiteInfo =new HashMap<String, URL>();
        titles =new ArrayList<String>();
        grabHTMLInfo();

        add(new JLabel("What website u wanna visit?"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainList=new JList(titles.toArray());

        mainList.addListSelectionListener(


        new ListSelectionListener() {

            //@Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

                Object object = mainList.getSelectedValue();
                URL newDocument = websiteInfo.get(object);
                AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();
                browser.showDocument(newDocument);

            }
        }
 );
        add(new JScrollPane(mainList),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
    private void grabHTMLInfo(){
        String title;
        String address;
        int counter=0;
        URL url;
        title=getParameter("title"+counter);
        while(title!=null){
            address=getParameter("address"+counter);
            try {
                url =new URL(address);
                websiteInfo.put(title, url);
                titles.add(title);
            } catch (MalformedURLException uRLException) {

                uRLException.printStackTrace();
            }
            ++counter;
            title=getParameter("title"+counter);
        }



    }


}
```

.java main:

```
package stringpractice;

public class appletMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

.HTML:

```
<html>
<title>testing applet</title>

<body>

<applet code="Applet.class" width="500" height="200">

<param name="title0" value="Google">
<param name="address0" value="https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=M8ovVKu9AujJ8gfH8oH4Cw">


<param name="title1" value="Yahoo">
<param name="address1" value="https://se.yahoo.com/">



</applet>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Change your init method declaration to: `public void init()`

Comment: Applets shouldn't have a `main` method

Comment: user432, that is even worse. Doesn't help. what it does is just stop displaying the applet window (after I add public).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init()` method is written as `inIt()`. As everything is case sensitive, your init method gets never called.